# Print preview using Javascript / Jquery in IE and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swt

I am developing an SWT java application which uses an embedded browser. I want to show the print preview of the browser page.Is it possible with jquery/javascript. `window.print()` does not show print preview  in safari and IE as it shows in chrome.I found one script http://jsfiddle.net/G6eU3/ which also works only on chrome.The script is

```
function printpage() {
    var data = '<script>alert("Print window");<\/script><table border="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td colspan="4">Sample Report</td></tr>' + document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML + '</table>';
    data += '<br/><button onclick="window.print()"  class="noprint">Print the Report</button>';
    data += '<style type="text/css" media="print"> .noprint {visibility: hidden;} </style>';
    myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

please suggest anything which will work either on safari or  IE.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java at all.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I want to write a script and run the script in the browser using Browser.execute(Script)

Comment: And how is [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) related to this in any way?

Comment: Because this is in no way related to Java.

Comment: @BoristheSpider because the browser is in a SWT Java application and there might be a java solution for this like if there is a function like browser.printPreview()

Comment: Down voting just of wrong tag is unfair!Next ,you might down vote for a spelling mistake too!